# Mondegreen Jobs

Tags: music

Everyone loves a good mondegreen (or [misheard song lyric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)), but sometimes they make me think that the artist should chuck in singing and take up a different job.

**The challenge** - From this list of artists and alternative jobs, work out what misheard song lyric made me think they should take this job. Answers should contain the misheard lyric, the original lyric, and the song it came from.

1. **Adele** has possibly been working as a *bailiff*
2. **Britney Spears** would make a good *butcher*
3. **Macy Gray** could become a *pastry chef*

*(NB All lines are from the chorus, and are hence repeated multiple times in the relevant songs)*

Comment: Are you asking about a well known line in a well known song, or could it be a random line you would only find when you search through all the lyrics a certain artist?

Comment: @PL457 - Good question. The lines/lyrics are all from the choruses and therefore hopefully not *too* obscure. Question updated.

Comment: Definitely not the answer, but the original chorus lyrics from "Oops, I Did It Again" could be misinterpreted that way - "I played with your **heart**, got lost in the **game**."

Comment: @DanielSchepler - You could definitely mondegreen that to get a good answer: "It's made from a heart, and also some game".

Comment: Think I read this one somewhere online: the Rolling Stones could open an Italian restaurant: "I'll never leave your pizzas burnin'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Adele

> Lyric as heard: *Should I give up or should I just keep chasing payments?*
>  Lyric as written: *Should I give up or should I just keep chasing pavements?*
>  Song title: *Chasing Pavements*

#### Britney

> Lyric as heard: *You want a piece of meat?*
>  Lyric as written: *You want a piece of me?*
>  Song title: *Piece of Me*

Comment: I have an idea what the original lyric might be for the Macy Gray one, but I can't figure out the mondegreen. Edit: and from Daniel's answer, it seems I was right.

Comment: Oh wow. Fail on my part. Adele does sing chasing pavements... For some reason I can only hear Macy grey when I think of that song lol

Comment: With 2 out of 3 you get the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 11):

First one

> Misheard lyric: Never mind, I'll fine someone like you
>  Original lyric: Never mind, I'll **find** someone like you
>  Song: Someone Like You

Second one (credit, my friend Evan)

> Misheard lyric: Oops I did it again. I flavoured your heart.
>  Original lyric: I played with your heart.
>  Song: Oops, I did it again

Comment: Nice try! Although related to the work of a bailiff, this isn't actually something they do. So not what I was looking for.

Comment: Ha ha ha, this answer is funny.

Comment: Or: "I want nothing but arrest for you."

Answer (score 10):

Macy Grey:

> Misheard lyric: My dough crumbles when you are not here.
>  Original lyric: My world crumbles when you are not here.
>  Song: "I Try"

Comment: Correct lyric, and actually a better mondegreen than the one I had in mind (I had apple rather than dough), so I'll declare this the correct answer. Accepted answer goes to Peter for getting the other two though.

Comment: @AndyT I figured it had to with that crumble line, but couldn't think of a word that could be misheard enough to fit before it. Because the only words I could interpret enough would be "world, war, or wall". I'm not quite sure how you heard dough or apple from it X)

Comment: @Sensoray - Not my own misheard lyric that one, it was a friend at school. Another friend heard "I wear goggles when you are not near" - no idea how he got that one either!

Comment: @AndyT I definitely hear the goggles :]

Comment: Ah, as in replace "my world crumbles" with "apple crumbles"?  I could hear that.

Comment: I occasionally also hear "Try to walk away but I crumble" in the earlier line which could also vaguely fit the clue.

Answer (score 0):

**Britney Spears**

> With the taste of your hips I'm on a ride

Original

> With the taste of your lips I'm on a ride

Song title:

> Toxic